# One tag, two acronyms

Tags: discussion, tags

I am talking about [wai](/questions/tagged/wai). In my world/line of work, WAi means [Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) that is part of the W3C. In others, it refers to something that is [part of the Haskell programming language](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WebApplicationInterface).

Is this a thing that people should just deal with or should [w3c-wai](/questions/tagged/w3c-wai) and [haskell-wai](/questions/tagged/haskell-wai) be created and people should append the correct tags. For most questions regarding W3C def, they are also tagged [correctly] with [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) and Haskell-related ones with [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell).

Comment: I don't know, if there are lots of questions tagged `wai` only it might be a problem, but there are lots of cases I see where `query` or `cursor` is used as a tag, but I never see them alone, they're always combined with the tech the question involves (e.g. `sql-server` or `oracle`). I think it would be artificial to enforce some kind of "this word is ambiguous or too generic therefore can never be used as a tag" rule.

Comment: I am not saying we should enforce a rule, I am saying should we make topic specific tags, and retag them? The excerpt for wai could be "Wai is usually referring to w3c wai or wai within haskell, please use add w3c-wai or haskell-wai for better filtering"

Comment: it sounds like a lot of work for little gain. Folks will still use the `wai` tag as long as it exists, and will they really think to look for a `haskell-wai` tag? I don't know the space but again I think about this in terms of my space. I wouldn't want to have to use a tag like `sql-server-cursor` when the question is already tagged `sql-server`. Seems redundant to me.

Comment: +1 that would essentially mean you have to follow `sql-server-cursor` just in case somebody used only `sql-server-cursor` vs `sql-server-cursor` and `sql-server`

Comment: Right, I find that making hybrid tags will just lead to a different problem. If someone tags `wai` only with no tagged indication of which area they meant, you should be able to update those based on the question context, and it would be less work than trying to update and re-tag *all* questions that have a tag `wai` and are also correctly tagged with `haskell` or `w3c`. Again, seems redundant.

Comment: Just to be nitpicky, [wai](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai) is not part of the Haskell programming language, it's just a library written in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will get much better "bang for your buck" by finding isolated cases where users are tagging *only* with [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) and educating them about being more specific. This should be a much smaller workload and should be very easy to explain based on the context of the question.

As I mentioned in my comments:

> I don't know, if there are lots of questions tagged [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) only it might be a problem, but there are lots of cases I see where [query](/questions/tagged/query) or [cursor](/questions/tagged/cursor) is used as a tag, but I never see them alone, they're always combined with the tech the question involves (e.g. [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) or [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)). I think it would be artificial to enforce some kind of "this word is ambiguous or too generic therefore can never be used as a tag" rule.

> It sounds like a lot of work for little gain. Folks will still use the [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) tag as long as it exists, and will they really think to look for a [haskell-wai](/questions/tagged/haskell-wai) tag? I don't know the space but again I think about this in terms of my space. I wouldn't want to have to use a tag like [sql-server-cursor](/questions/tagged/sql-server-cursor) when the question is already tagged [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). Seems redundant to me.

> Right, I find that making hybrid tags will just lead to a different problem. If someone tags [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) only with no tagged indication of which area they meant, you should be able to update those based on the question context, and it would be less work than trying to update and re-tag *all* questions that have a tag [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) and are also correctly tagged with [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) or [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c). Again, seems redundant.

Comment: If [tag:sql-server-cursor] and [tag:oracle-cursor] do not strike everyone as semantically unrelated beasts comparable with [tag:wai], let's just add [tag:text-editor-cursor] to the mix.  Yes, [tag:cursor] covers UI cursors as well.