# Multi meaning acronyms tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The problem has been asked before, but under a slightly different conditions.

There are acronyms, that have multiple meanings based on the context, like for example in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139712/one-tag-two-acronyms) [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) which can mean [w3c-wai](/questions/tagged/w3c-wai) or [haskell-wai](/questions/tagged/haskell-wai). In such cases, the solution is quite simple - we can retag questionsso they are more specific and not use [wai](/questions/tagged/wai) at all (mark it as "deprecated"). But in some cases, adding any additional information to the tag discards the actual justification of acronym usage in the first place.

Lets consider `machine learning`, it's common acronym is `ml` (or even more common `ML`). In the same time, on stack overflow we have [ml](/questions/tagged/ml) which points to the

> ML is a family of functional programming languages, created by the Turing awarded computer scientist Robin Milner. It was initially created as the metalanguage for a theorem prover (hence the name), but quickly became used as a general-purpose programming language. One of ML most famous characteristics is type inference supporting parametric polymorphism.

Of course we could create artificial tags like [ai-ml](/questions/tagged/ai-ml) and [language-ml](/questions/tagged/language-ml), but using acronyms is justified by their simplicity, and I don't think that actuall anyone asking about machine learning would come up with tag [ai-ml](/questions/tagged/ai-ml) (or [ml-ml](/questions/tagged/ml-ml) ;)). I currently simply retag questions with [ml](/questions/tagged/ml) in cotext of machine learning to [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning), but I don't think it is isolated issue.

Is there an already developed way of dealing with such phenomen? Or is it too rare to be considered?

Comment: A technically feasible option would be to infer which of the specific tags it refers to based on the other tags used, but I don't think that would work too well in practice. (I.e. as well as synonyms you could have context sensitive synonyms).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings?rq=1 - and follow the links. Ambiguous tags are a problem, acronyms is just a special case.

Comment: Most all acronyms are initialisms, not all initialisms are acronyms